# Error: Hive hbase connectivity issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I tried to add the property below in hive-site.xml

```
 <property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>
file:///home/hduser/hive/setup/lib/zookeeper3.4.6.jar,file:///home/hduser/hive/setup/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar,file:///home/hduser/hive/setup/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-server-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-shell-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-thrift-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-annotations-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.1.2.jar,file:///home/hduser/hbase/setup/lib/hbase-resource-bundle-1.1.2.jar</value>
  </property>
```

Getting Below Error while executing command:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val") TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");

**FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V**
```